# Blazor Webassembly and OData (MVC does not exist in the namespace Microsoft.Aspnetcore)

Tags: asp.net-core, odata, .net-5, blazor-webassembly

I am using Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2019, Version 16.9.2.

I have started a new Blazor WebAssembly project, target framework is .NET 5.0 and the project is configured for HTTPS, and the ASP.NET Core hosted option is selected.

The problem is when I try to Install `Microsoft.AspNetCore.OData` nuget package (version8.0.0 pre release 3).

After Installation, I build the project, and I got the following error:

> CS0234    The type or namespace name 'Mvc' does not exist in the namespace 'Microsoft.AspNetCore' (are you missing an assembly reference?)
>
> Build started: Project: WebApplication1.Client, Configuration: Debug Any CPU
>
> CS0234: The type or namespace name 'Mvc' does not exist in the namespace 'Microsoft.AspNetCore' (are you missing an assembly reference?)

Any help will be highly appreciated

Thanks

Comment: The `Microsoft.AspNetCore.OData` nuget package contains everything you need to create OData
endpoints using ASP.NET Core **MVC** and to support OData query syntax for your **web APIs**. So, you could install it in the `WebApplication1.Server` project, instead of the `WebApplication1.Client` project. To use OData Client with Blazor WebAssembly client project, you can use the [Microsoft OData Connected Service](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/odata/connectedservice/getting-started), reference [this article](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/odata/client/using-blazor-wasm-with-odata-client).

Comment: I have created a blazor application.

Comment: I have created a blazor application. it has three projects  client, server and shared. i have installed odata package in all three projects. when i build this solution, server and shared project are ok  but there is problem with client. thanks

Comment: Hi @user3531016, Yes, I know the blazor application has three projects, as I said in my previous comment. For the client project, there is no need to add the `Microsoft.AspNetCore.OData` nuget package, so, try to uninstall it. In the Client project, if you want to use OData, try to use **Microsoft OData Connected Service**.